# I cannot change image slides

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4, and carousel seems not working.I can see my active image and next and previous icon but I cannot change slide when I press icons.

```css
.carousel-inner img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
```

```html
 @* Image Slider  *@

        <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ul class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="~/Image/bg.jpg" alt="Clinic1" width="1100" height="500" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption ">
                        <h3>Clinic 1</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="~/Image/bg.jpg" alt="Clinic2" width="1100" height="500" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Clinic 2</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="~/Image/bg.jpg" alt="Clinic3" width="1100" height="500" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption container-fluid">
                        <h3>Clinic 3</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: I copy/pasted your code in https://jsfiddle.net/websitelerimiz/jby7L0z1/. And seems like it works. Please clarify your question about what's not working.

Comment: Image slide is not changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a Dummyimg gerenrator, adding the [Bootstrap CSS, JS (Together with jQuery and all)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/) it seems to be working fine.

Did you check your images path?

```js
$('.carousel').carousel()
```

```css
.carousel-inner img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ul class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=img1" alt="Clinic1" width="1100" height="500" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption ">
                        <h3>Clinic 1</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=img2" alt="Clinic2" width="1100" height="500" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Clinic 2</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=img2" alt="Clinic3" width="1100" height="500" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption container-fluid">
                        <h3>Clinic 3</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Just in case I added the JavaScript code from the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/carousel/) to force it:

```
$('.carousel').carousel()
```